# Proper config settings for OpenVPN server to route through GCP Cloud VPN Gateway?

Tags: vpn, openvpn, google-cloud

**Scenario**

I want to connect my team to a remote server via a VPN. This VPN has to go through some rules the remote server has which are described below.
I have setup OpenVPN but am open to trying any other VPN solution.

Connecting to a remote server via the following:
Laptop -> VPN Client (Viscosity) -> OpenVPN server running on VM on Google Cloud -> Google Cloud VPN -> IPSec using IKEv2 connection to remote Gateway -> Remote server

The VM runs in a Virtual Private Cloud in Google Cloud, which has internal IP ranges of 172.25.165.0/26 and Gateway is 172.25.165.1

The remote server is in a local IP range of 172.23.133.0/24 (172.23.133.1)
Its gateway has a rule set that it must be connected to via an IP in range of 172.25.165.0/26

My VPN client is typically assigned 172.25.165.5 after connecting

Cloud VPN has a tunnel setup:
VPN tunnel inner IP stack type
IPv4
Multiprotocol BGP
Disabled IPv6
Advertised IP ranges
172.23.133.0/24
Local subnetworks
lnetwork 172.25.165.0/26

Routes in Google Cloud show as such:

| Name | Description | Destination IP range | Priority | Next Hop |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| default-route-1 | Default route to the Internet | 0.0.0.0/0 | 1000 | VPN tunnel |
| default-route-1b | Default local route to the subnetwork | 172.25.165.0/26 | 0 | VPN |
| tunnel-2-route-1 |  | 172.23.133.0/24 | 1000 | VPN tunnel |

Firewall is set to allow all ingress and egress for those routes

IP Forwarding is On for the VM

**OpenVPN config**

```
local 172.25.165.2
port 1194
proto tcp-server
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
auth SHA512
tls-crypt tc.key
mode server
tls-server
topology subnet
push "topology subnet"
ifconfig 172.25.165.3 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool 172.25.165.5 172.25.165.200 255.255.255.0
route-gateway 172.25.165.2
push "route-gateway 172.25.165.2"
push "route 172.25.165.5 255.255.255.0 172.23.133.17"

ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
verb 3
crl-verify crl.pem
log /var/log/openvpn/openvpn.log
```

**Notes**

I can successfully connect to the remote server if I ssh into the VM
I can also successfully tunnel my traffic via the VM from my laptop
sshuttle also works for connecting via the vm to the remote
I can ping the remote server via the vm

I can successfully connect to the OpenVPN server using a local client (either Viscosity or OpenVPN client)

However, I cannot successfully to the remote server once connected to the VPN
Attempting to ping the remote server on the VPN results in "Network is unreachable"

There is nothing in the OpenVPN logs on the server that seems relevant.

I have tried many different combinations of OpenVPN server config changes as well as client config changes but no success. I've also tried adding routes directly on the vm. I also have had no success with trying via OpenVPN Open Access server which results in the same issue. I have been at this for over 3 days and have read as much documentation on OpenVPN as I can find and many StackExchange questions on OpenVPN but have been unable to find an answer. Most existing answers seem to point to the firewall or the routing as being the problem. I'm not seeing any blocked events in the firewall log (and it is set to open for all these ranges) so I am assuming I am doing something wrong in trying to route the traffic in the OpenVPN config. How can I set up the vm and network and config to work in this scenario?

Comment: If I change the config to a more default 10.x.x.x IP range then it seems to function to access the rest of the internet (e.g. google.com ) but has no route to 172.23.133.17
In certain configs trying to start the server in a 172.25.165.0/26 range results in an error of 
2022-07-15 11:13:09 sitnl_send: rtnl: generic error (-101): Network is unreachable
2022-07-15 11:13:09 ROUTE_GATEWAY 172.25.165.1

Comment: Is there something preventing you from using a  masquerade rule?
Also, Have you tried setting the VPN IP addresses on the nic and making sure it works?

Comment: @Behrooz As far as I know there is nothing preventing from properly setting a masquerade rule, however previous attempts at setting a masquerade rule have not worked. Guidance on proper application of one would be something I would readily try. I'm not exactly sure what "tried setting the VPN IP addresses on the nic and making sure it works" is implying exactly in terms of concrete commands, but I can say that connecting to the remove server directly via the virtual machine the OpenVPN server runs on works fine. It is only connecting through OpenVPN via the client to remote that does not work.

Comment: Have you tried with a different client operating system than Windows 7+?

Comment: did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: unfortunately no, even people with strong networking backgrounds that I talked to didn't seem to know how to set something like this up